# How to set setinterval time dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I have a google graph ..which is refresed through a setinterval function...now i am facing a problem to set the setinterval time dynamically when a value is selected from the dropdown .  for exampe if dropdown value is a or b then interval time will be 5 seconds and if value is c or d then interval time will be 5 mnutes.... at the time of page load i get the dropdown value to be selected by $_GET method....

```
<select onchange=changeintervaltime()>
<option value="a"></option>
<option value="b"></option>
<option value="c"></option>
<option value="d"></option>
</select>

setInterval(setRefreshInterval, 5000);

function setRefreshInterval()
{
   //logic goes here
}

function changeintervaltime()
{
   //here i want to set the interval time dynamically
}
```

setRefreshInterval this function will be always called and i want to set the interval time dynamically onchange of the select box .... how i will do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select onchange=changeintervaltime()>
<option value="a"></option>
<option value="b"></option>
<option value="c"></option>
<option value="d"></option>
</select>

var interval = setInterval(setRefreshInterval, 5000);

function setRefreshInterval()
{
   //logic goes here
}

function changeintervaltime()
{
   //here i want to set the interval time dynamically
   //suppose you want to set timer for 3000 now so clear the interval and set it again
   clearInterval(interval);
   interval = setInterval(setRefreshInterval, 3000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to clear the interval and re-call `setInterval` with the new interval.

```js
let interval = setInterval(setRefreshInterval, 1000);

function setRefreshInterval()
{
  console.log('running');
}

function changeintervaltime()
{
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(setRefreshInterval, 500);
}
```

```html
<select onchange=changeintervaltime()>
<option value="a"></option>
<option value="b"></option>
<option value="c"></option>
<option value="d"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set setInterval value according to your dropdown value.

```
let timer = 1000 ; // Default timer value 
let interval = setInterval(setRefreshInterval, timer);

function setRefreshInterval()
{
  //  logic ...
}

function changeintervaltime(dropDownValue)
{

  if(dropDownValue == 'a' || dropDownValue =='b'){
     timer = 5000 // 5ms
  }else if(dropDownValue == 'c' || dropDownValue == 'd'){
     timer = 30000 // 5min
  }
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(setRefreshInterval, timer);
}
```

```
<select onchange=changeintervaltime(this.value)>
<option value="a"></option>
<option value="b"></option>
<option value="c"></option>
<option value="d"></option>
</select>
```